# Bind a click event to multiple <options> elements

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have a select menu, which I would like to bind a single click event to each of the `<option>` elements. The purpose of this is to add a class to the `<option>` elements when ever it is clicked/selected. Here is my html and Javascript. I am lacking a way to select the `<option>` elements and bind the event to them. Any and all assistance would be appreciated.

**Html:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    <label>Select Menu
      <select id="SelectMenu">
        <option value="husker">Husker</option>
        <option value="starbuck">Starbuck</option>
        <option value="hotdog">Hot Dog</option>
        <option value="apollo">Apollo</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log("Click Event");
}
var options = document.getElementById('SelectMenu');
for ( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
  console.log(options[i].value);
  options[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false)
}
```

[Code example](http://codepen.io/fmrogers/pen/vGNxRE)

Comment: You don't bind events to `<option>`s. You bind a single `change` handler to the `<select>`, and then do the appropriate thing based on the `.value` that is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what your code does:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log("Click Event");
}
```

Pretty straightforward, a function.

Next up,

```
var options = document.getElementById('SelectMenu');
```

So, `options` is assigned the `#SelectMenu` element. Ok.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
  console.log(options[i].value);
  options[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false)
}
```

Now, here you start to get it a little wrong.

You don't have to add a listener to each and every `option` element in there.

The `select` element (yout `options` variable) emits a [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event every time you select another option.

So you can simply do

```
options.addEventListener('change', myFunction)
```

and that's it.

If you want to know which `option` element was clicked you should also define an event parameter to your callback function, like this

```
function myFunction(e) {
  //e.target is the <select> element
  console.log(e.target.value);
  console.log("Click Event");
}
```

There is not much point to adding a class to the clicked `option` element since you cannot style them.

UPDATE: Since you ask specifically to add a class to the selected option anyway, here's how you can do it:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  //e.target is the <select> element
  console.log(e.target.selectedOptions[0]);
  console.log(e.target.value);
  console.log("Click Event");
}
```

Cheers Frederick.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I was about to go mental trying to figure this out. It works perfectly. The adding of the class is for data collection. Now i just have to limit the class to a single option preventing multiple <option> tags from having the same class. ** cracks knuckles **

Answer (score 1):

better to create one event for the select then check the value in the event

```
function selectClicked(id){
  console.log(id);
  myFunction() ;
}
function myFunction() {
  console.log("Click Event");
}
var options = document.getElementById('SelectMenu');
options.setAttribute("onchange", function(){selectClicked(options.value);});
```